# Why the input of Scanf is always 0?

Tags: input, go, scanf

I'm trying to get input from a user and print it out, but apparently the value of the distance is `0`, after I did some input.

Here's the code:

```
type Person struct {
    name string
    age int
    ambition string
}

func (p *Person) walking() {
    var distance int
    fmt.Println("Enter the distance")
    fmt.Scanf("%f", &distance)

    if distance < 9 {
        fmt.Println(p.name, " is walking towards that direction in ", distance,
            "kilometer")
    } else {
        fmt.Println("This is an error, ignore this")
    }
}
```

As you can see whenever I try to run this command on my main function, it always prints `fmt.Println(p.name, " is walking towards that direction in ", distance, "kilometer")` even though the value of distance is more than `9`.

```
func main() {
    p := new(Person)
    p.name = "Joker"

    p.walking()
}
```

`p.walking()` will always print distance as `0`? Can anyone explain to me what is going on here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You used a wrong format string. `%f` is used to scan floating point numbers, but your variable `distance` is of type `int`, so you should use `%d`:

```
fmt.Scanf("%d", &distance)
```

Or declare `distance` variable to be a floating point number and then you can use `%f`:

```
var distance float64
fmt.Println("Enter the distance")
fmt.Scanf("%f", &distance)
```

**Note:**

[`fmt.Scanf()`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Scanf) returns the number of items successfully scanned, and an optional error. You should get used to handle errors in Go which would save you a lot of time.

As a minimal by storing and printing the return values of `Scanf()`:

```
var distance int
fmt.Println("Enter the distance")
n, err := fmt.Scanf("%f", &distance)
fmt.Println(n, err)
```

Prints:

```
0 bad verb %f for integer
```

Which immediately tells you `0` items were scanned and there was an error: `bad verb %f for integer` which is pretty much self explanatory.

This also explains why you always see `0` kilomenters printed: your `distance` variable is initialized to `0` (zero value of `int`) and it is never changed.

If scanning would be successful, you would see an output of:

```
1 <nil>
```

Meaning that one item was scanned successfully (the `distance`) and there was no error.

If you would scan multiple items with one `Scanf()` call, `n` could be greater than `1` of course (for example `fmt.Scanf("%f %d", &distance, &temp)`).

Comment: Thank you! such a detailed explanation

Comment: One question, I tried to print the value of n variable, and it always show **1**?, why is that?

Comment: @airsoftFreak Because `n` tells how many items were scanned successfully, and it is `1` in your case (the `distance`). It could be greater than `1` if you would scan multiple items with one `Scanf()` call. See edited answer.